# Given an array of integers as input, return true if the array is sorted. Note that the array can be sorted in either ascending or descending order

Tags: java

Sample Input #1

```
isSorted([1,3,5,7})
```

Sample Output #1

```
true
```

Sample Input #2

```
isSorted({11,9,2,-5})
```

Sample Output #2

```
true
```

Sample Input #3

```
isSorted({1,2,3,4,-1,-2})
```

```
public boolean isSorted(int[] arr){

    boolean isSorted = false;
    if(arr.length==1)
    return true;

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++)
    {

        if(arr[i]<arr[i+1])
        {
            isSorted = true;
        }
        else if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            isSorted = true;
        }
        else
            isSorted = false;

        if(isSorted != true)
            return isSorted;
    }
    return isSorted;
}
```

What happens to my code some of my testcase didn't pass
parameter '{24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42}' pass
parameter '{1,3,5,7,4}'               fail

Comment: Time to debug your code, no?

Comment: Your `isSorted` calls don't work as written. Change method to `public static boolean isSorted(int ... arr) {`, and drop the braces on your calls, e.g. `isSorted(1,3,5,7)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a single `boolean` variable to keep two bits of information, which does not work. You need two `boolean`s here - one to indicate that the array is sorted in ascending order, and another one to indicate that the array is sorted in descending order.

Prepare two variables, `isAscending = true` and `isDescending = true`. Go through the array the way you do now, and set the corresponding variable to `false` if you detect an inversion. Never set these variables to `true` again, because a single inversion breaks the sort order.

```
if (arr[i]<arr[i+1]) isDescending = false;
if (arr[i]>arr[i+1]) isAscending = false;
```

That's all you need to do. Once the loop is over, `isAscending || isDescending` expression gives you the answer.

To speed up an exit from your `for` loop, use this termination condition:

```
i<arr.length-1 && (isAscending || isDescending)
```

Answer (score 1):

Logic:

- Loop through list with an index counter
- First, forward index while next two values are equal
- If next value is less than current value, do descending check
- If next value is greater than current value, do ascending check
- Verify that all remaining values are ascending/descending, or equal

Answer (score 0):

I have a different proposition than the one from Andreas :

- Initialize booleans `ascending` and `descending` to `true`
- Store item 0, iterate from item 1. While either or the booleans is true, store the current value and increment the index. During each loop, update the two booleans (for example for the first one : `ascending = ascending && previousElement <= currentElement`
- return `ascending || descending`

Answer (score 0):

You need another var to indicate the sorting:ascending or descending

```
short srt = 0;//-1 descending, +1ascending
```

then compare the two first val to decide the sorting sense, so I propose this solution:

```
public boolean isSorted(int[] arr){

short srt = 0;//-1 descending, +1ascending

if(arr.length <= 2)
    return true;
else {
    if(arr[0] < arr[1])
        srt = 1;
    else
        srt = -1

for(int i=1;i<arr.length-1;i++)
    if((arr[i] < arr[i+1] && srt = -1) || (arr[i] > arr[i+1] && srt = 1)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

}